# Header information printed many times when imported to a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get certain datas after parsing 100s of XMLs. Finally, i am writing the data to a CSV file. The problem is that the header is printed in alternate lines. How can i get the header printed only on the first line?

My Piece of code:

```py
def main():
    asset_metadata = glob.glob(os.path.join(ASSET_METADATA_PATH, u'*.xml'))
    movies = glob.glob(os.path.join(TS_PATH, u'*.ts'))
    subtitles = glob.glob(os.path.join(TS_PATH, '*.pac'))
    content_list = extract_id(asset_metadata)
    show = []
    filecount = 0
    for p in asset_metadata:
        filecount += 1
        print(u'Processing: {p}'.format(p=p).encode('utf-8'))
        content_id, content_name, has_trailer, trailer_id, series_id = parse_file(p)
        movie_path = os.path.join(TS_PATH, '{c}.ts'.format(c=content_id))
        subtitles_ara = os.path.join(TS_PATH, '{c}.pac'.format(c=content_id + " -ara"))
        subtitles_eng = os.path.join(TS_PATH, '{c}.pac'.format(c=content_id + " -eng"))
        MOVIE_ERROR = ""
        TRAILER_ERROR = ""
        SHOW_ERROR = ""
        SUBTITLE_ARA_ERROR = ""
        SUBTITLE_ENG_ERROR = ""
        ERROR = 0
        if movie_path not in movies:
            MOVIE_ERROR = "No"
            ERROR = 1
        if has_trailer == "Y":
            trailer_path = os.path.join(TS_PATH, '{c}.ts'.format(c=trailer_id))
            if trailer_path not in movies:
                TRAILER_ERROR = "No"
                ERROR = 1
        if subtitles_ara not in subtitles:
            SUBTITLE_ARA_ERROR = "No"
            ERROR = 1
        if subtitles_eng not in subtitles:
            SUBTITLE_ENG_ERROR = "No"
            ERROR = 1
        if series_id not in content_list:
            SHOW_ERROR = "No"
            show.append(series_id)
        if ERROR == 1:
            with open("xml_validate.csv", mode='a') as file:
                fieldnames = ['Movie ID', 'Movie Title', 'Movie Available', 'Trailer Available', 'Show/Season Id', 'Show/Season Available', 'Arabic Subtitles', 'English Subtitles']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow(
                    {'Movie ID': content_id, 'Movie Title': content_name, 'Movie Available': MOVIE_ERROR,
                     'Trailer Available': TRAILER_ERROR, 'Show/Season Id': series_id, 'Show/Season Available': SHOW_ERROR, 'Arabic Subtitles': SUBTITLE_ARA_ERROR, 'English Subtitles':SUBTITLE_ENG_ERROR})
```

I am attaching the screenshot as well.[image]

How can i get only the headers printed only on the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `csv.DictWriter` instance every time and appending it to the existing file.  Instead, consider opening the file once (outside of the loop), and proceeding to write a single CSV line by line.  Something like this:

```py
fieldnames = ['Movie ID', 'Movie Title', 'Movie Available', 'Trailer Available', 'Show/Season Id', 'Show/Season Available', 'Arabic Subtitles', 'English Subtitles']
with open("xml_validate.csv", mode='a') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for p in asset_metadata:
        # do all that other stuff...

        if ERROR == 1:
            writer.writerow(
                {
                    'Movie ID': content_id,
                    'Movie Title': content_name,
                    'Movie Available': MOVIE_ERROR,
                    'Trailer Available': TRAILER_ERROR,
                    'Show/Season Id': series_id,
                    'Show/Season Available': SHOW_ERROR,
                    'Arabic Subtitles': SUBTITLE_ARA_ERROR,
                    'English Subtitles':SUBTITLE_ENG_ERROR
                }
            )
```

Comment: Getting this error.   File "validator.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "validator.py", line 114, in main
    'Trailer Available': TRAILER_ERROR, 'Show/Season Id': series_id, 'Show/Season Available': SHOW_ERROR, 'Arabic Subtitles': SUBTITLE_ARA_ERROR, 'English Subtitles':SUBTITLE_ENG_ERROR})
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: did you un-indent after opening the file?  Note that the whole loop in my example is within the context manager.

Comment: sweet!  glad to help